# NSMutableArray enumerating objects

Tags: objective-c

How can I enumerate the values of the instances in this code through fast enumeration, It's returning addresses of the arrays, and also I feel like there is a short way for doing this.

```
BNRStockHolding *stockHolding = [[BNRStockHolding alloc] init];
[stockHolding setPurchasedSharePrice:2.30];
[stockHolding setCurrentSharePrice:4.50];
[stockHolding setNumberOfShares:40];
float p = [stockHolding purchasedSharePrice];
float c = [stockHolding currentSharePrice];
int n = [stockHolding numberOfShares];
float cost = [stockHolding costInDollars];
float val = [stockHolding valueInDollars];

BNRStockHolding *stockHolding1 = [[BNRStockHolding alloc] init];
[stockHolding setPurchasedSharePrice:12.19];
[stockHolding setCurrentSharePrice:10.56];
[stockHolding setNumberOfShares:90];
float p1 = [stockHolding purchasedSharePrice];
float c1 = [stockHolding currentSharePrice];
int n1 = [stockHolding numberOfShares];
float cost1 = [stockHolding costInDollars];
float val1 = [stockHolding valueInDollars];

BNRStockHolding *stockHolding2 = [[BNRStockHolding alloc] init];
[stockHolding setPurchasedSharePrice:45.10];
[stockHolding setCurrentSharePrice:49.51];
[stockHolding setNumberOfShares:210];
float p2 = [stockHolding purchasedSharePrice];
float c2 = [stockHolding currentSharePrice];
int n2 = [stockHolding numberOfShares];
float cost2 = [stockHolding costInDollars];
float val2 = [stockHolding valueInDollars];

NSMutableArray *threeInstances = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
    stockHolding, stockHolding1, stockHolding2, nil];

for(BNRStockHolding *d in threeInstances) {
    NSLog(@"%@", d);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: You should be using NSDecimalNumber to store currency.

Comment: I want to print the values of the prices

Comment: Forget about fast enumeration.  That's a convenience, not an essential feature.  Decide what you want to do with the data, and if fast enumeration works then use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to modify your `BNRStockHolding` class, it'd look something like this:

```
for(BNRStockHolding *d in threeInstances) {
    NSLog(@"Number of shares: %d", [d numberOfShares]);
    NSLog(@"PurchasedSharePrice: %f, CurrentSharePrice: %f", [d 
        purchasedSharePrice], [d currentSharePrice]);
}
```

Comment: works perfectly! thank you so much! I can finally sleep.

Answer (score 3):

Do you just want to print the objects? If so try defining the `description` method in your BNRStockHolding class. Like this:

```
- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"PurchasedSharePrice=%f, CurrentSharePrice=%f", purchasedSharePrice, currentSharePrice];
}
```

Instead of printing the addresses it will print out the NSString you defined in there.

Comment: I want all the values in array and fast enumerate all the values

Comment: Implementing this method in your `BNRStockHolding` class and changing nothing else will do that.

Comment: Sure, you just have to add any other values you want printed in the NSString above.